# Bootstrap Wizard Is Not Moving To Next Page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently seeking some help on using the bootstrapWizard plugin for my ajax request. When the form submits successfully it does not move to the next page in the form. Can someone help me figure out why with my following code. When the form submits it does have the success key set to true in the response so it is returning correctly.

```
$("#pageOneSubmission").click(function() {
    ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ route('...') }}',
        data:
            {
                ...
            },
        dataType: JSON,
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                console.log("Errors");
                $('#orderForm').bootstrapWizard({onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    alert('on tab click disabled');
                    return false;
                }});
            } else {
                $('#orderForm').bootstrapWizard({onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    nextTab($('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active'));
                }});
                console.log("No Errors");
                alert('no errors');
                swal({
                    title: "Success!!",
                    text: "Your order & patient profile are saved!",
                    timer: 2500,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    type: "success"
                });



            }
        },
        error: function(jqXhr) {
            if (jqXhr.status === 422) {
                alert('testing with errors');
                var err = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText);
                // $('#orderForm').bootstrapWizard('disable', $('#step2').data('tabindex'));
                // this wouldn't work cause your redirecting the page, the loop
                // wouldn't loop...
                // window.location = $('#orderForm').attr('action');
                $.each(err, function(key, value) {
                // $('input [name="'+ key +'"]').next().append("<p>Test</p>");
                    $('#'+data.errors[I][0]+'').css({'border':'#F00'});
                });
            }
        }
    }, function(){
        setTimeout(function() {

        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it because the success logic is also written in the funciton 'onTabClick'? Doesn't it mean that you have to click on the tab to execute that logic?

Comment: Perhaps. Have  you used it before? If so what do I need to change?

Comment: I haven't used it before but I may be able to help. Can you give me the link of the plugin you are using?